# Find common elements in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of all company objects

```
const all= [{'text': 'first'}, {'text':'second'},{'text:': 'third'}]
```

And also an array of the current company

```
const current = [{'text:': 'third'}]
```

Help to leave only those "text" elements that are not duplicated in
array that called "all"

I try to find solution but I miss experience

```js
const all= [{'text': 'first'}, {'text':'second'},{'text:': 'third'}]

const current = [{'text:': 'third'}]

function test(){
  const result =  all.filter(el=>{
    if(all.some(element=> el.text === element.text)){
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  })
  
  console.log(result)
}

test()
```

!it is important that the search should be named by text as the id may differ

Comment: Please add desired outcome to clarify the question.

Comment: there is a typo - "text:"

Comment: What is the need for current array in this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const all= [{'text': 'first'}, {'text':'second'},{'text:': 'third'}];
const current = [{'text:': 'third'}];

all.filter(ele => !current.some(cur => cur.text === ele.text))

// output
// [{text: "first"}, {text: "second"}]
```

There are many ways to solve this. You could use a simple for loop, but JS has built-in methods on an array type:

.filter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

and

.some (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

When you read the function out, it says "filter all the array (all), if `some` of the `current` element's `text` is equal to that element from `all`, remove it (`!`)"

Comment: @DonaldDuck thank you for pointing that out. Hopefully the edit does it!